# Developer-friendly, e-commerce (Magento)-adapted, EU-compliant PoS software

Tags: web-services, ecommerce, magento, point-of-sale

I'm currently looking for a Point of Sales software to plug in with our Magento website. Currently we use [Hiboutik](http://www.hiboutik.fr/), but the connector is not so good and the API does not allow us to handle all the entities we can create inside it (like gift card accounts). This software is a good reference, but it is still a very young technology and lacks many functionalities.
Here are our requirements :

- compliance with EU laws (RGPD)
- completely API-ready
- if possible, a web interface (so we can use the software as well on PC as tablets)
- if possible also, existing Magento connector
- advanced functionalities, like gift card accounts, discount campaigns, mail sending, client profiles and such

The whole goal is to pilot the software and the campains of our physical shop from our e-shop, with CRONs, scripts, and to centralize stock and orders data on our e-shop.

We already looked into those software, which didn't satisfy our needs :

- Fastmag
- Lineosoft

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you did not like in Fastmag and Lineosoft, so that we know better what you want, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another noteworthy option is Shopify's PoS system. It provides comprehensive functionalities, compliance with EU regulations, and an easy-to-use web interface.

Answer (score 0):

One popular option that has gained traction in recent years is Square. It offers a robust PoS system with an extensive API, compliance with EU laws, and a user-friendly web interface suitable for both PCs and tablets. Square also integrates well with e-commerce platforms, including Magento, allowing for a seamless connection between your physical shop and e-shop.
If you'd like more information about migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2, you can check out [https://transformagency.com/magento-1-to-magento-2-migration/](https://transformagency.com/magento-1-to-magento-2-migration). It'll provide you with some insights to make the transition smoother.